# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, babeljs

In our application, we used the library of icons, which was created by the first developers and was no longer supported by the new version of the `react` (`16.0 and higher`)

We decided to leave their previous look, just by slightly changing the code so that it worked, and to make it as a `Component`.

Here is how it look's now:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as icons from 'icons';

class Icon extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        type: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.keys(icons)).isRequired
    };

    render() {
        const {type, ...other} = this.props;
        const IconComponent = icons[type];

        return IconComponent ? (
            <IconComponent {...other}/>
        ) : null;
    }
}

export * from '/icons';
export default Icon;
```

In theory, everything should work fine, since other components in this directory are written in a similar way.

But there is an error that I have never faced before:

```
00:14:58 App /home/cpt/Desktop/prod/local/app/components/Base/Elements/IconSocial/index.js:3
00:14:58 App import _Object$defineProperty from 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/define-property';
00:14:58 App ^^^^^^
00:14:58 App SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Error points to this line: `import * as icons from 'icons';`

We use `babel-core": "6.26.3"`

Tell me, please, what could possibly be? Thanks in advance for any of your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a babel issue. Here you can read about it: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2877

Possible solution would be to add that to plugins:

```
"plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", { "polyfill": false }]
]
```

Comment: I didn’t understand how it works, but it helped, thank you very much :)